# Is it possible to migrate data from one cargo crate registry to another?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I need to migrate from one rust cargo alternative registry (i.e. *not* crates.io) to another (unrelated) one.

Many crates have been published in the current alternate registry, and many of them depend on both crates.io and the alternate registry (through `registry = "..."` key in `Cargo.toml`).

Is there a defined way to migrate the crates from the first alternate registry to the second? If not, what would be the best approach for this migration?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of crates and versions, downloading them all from `$registry/api/v1/crates/$crate/$version/download`, unpacking them, editing `registries = …` with sed or a small rust-snippet based on toml-edit, and then re-`cargo publish`ing them should do. (Maybe an additional `mv Cargo.toml.orig Cargo.toml` is nice.) The only complication I can think of is that the build done by `cargo publish` might fail unless you re-publish in the order the crates were originally published. If you like to live dangerously, you can skip that with `--no-verify`, but unless you can delete crates from your target registry (i.e. roll back a failed migration attempt), I would avoid that.